# Displaying conditional Fields in HTML Using A Form Select Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to get my page to display different form elements depending on which option is selected from the select menu but i can not get it to work for me

my HTML is

```
 <h3>Register For General Admission</h3>

<form action="GeneralRegister" method="POST" style="text-align:center">
Type Of Ticket: <select name="typeofticket" size="1" id="generalAdmissionList">
    <option value="1"></option>
    <option value="1">General Admission</option>
    <option value="1">General Admission School</option>
</select>
<br>
<div id="1">
    <!--for general admission-->
    First name:
    <input type="text" name="firstname">
    <br>Last name:
    <input type="text" name="lastname">
    <br>
</div>
<div id="2">
    <!--For Schools-->
    School name:
    <input type="text" name="school">
    <br>
</div>
Email:
<input type="text" name="email">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<br>
</form>
```

and my JavaScript is

```
$("#generalAdmissionList").change(function () {
var selected = $("#generalAdmissionList option:selected").form();
$('div').hide();
$('#' + selected).show();
});

$(document).ready(function (e) {
$('div').hide();
});
```

any help would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your select options to this

```
<option value="1">General Admission</option>
<option value="2">General Admission School</option>
```

and the javascript line to get the selected value should be like this

```
var selected = $("#generalAdmissionList option:selected").val();
```

Comment: Thank you.. fixed it straight away.. its bin bugging me for the last few hours and just couldn't find what i was doing wron